# In Flex 3, how I insert the company logo as an icon in the browser tab?

Tags: apache-flex, jboss, flex3

I m building an application on flex and need the company logo to insert as an icon in the browser tab (e.g of IE 7, Chrome or firefox) and also in the title bar of the browser. I achieved this by using index file, but when I use .swf in address bar than JBoss icon is displaying on title bar because application is deployed on JBoss Server. In short when I am use .swf in address bar and application is deployed in JBoss server then I want to replace title bar icon with default JBoss icon in flex 3.

Comment: This is more of a `JBoss` question; Flex doesn't have any control over the favicon that the browser requests.

Answer (score 1):

To change the "favicon" in JBoss you can do:

JBoss 5:

1. Navigate to the folder "{JBOSS_ROOT}\server\all\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar\ROOT.war" and replace the "favicon" with the one you like.
2. Restart your JBoss application server
3. Clear cache of your browser.

JBoss 8.1 WildFly:

- Change the icon file available at {WILDFLY_HOME}\welcome-content\favicon.ico

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we have multiple clients and each client have their own company logo and we deployed separate ears for each client, the solution you suggested may change the logo for all clients.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put those information in **main.html** or **index.html** as below assuming you have **companyLogo.ico** file in that folder.

```
<head>
     <title>Company Title</title>
     <link rel="icon" href="companyLogo.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
... ...
```

Comment: Yes you right but the solution you suggested I already implemented as I mentioned in my question, the index file is a HTML file. My question is to use logo without using HTML/Index file.